# Get app visible for tablets in Play store

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have the below manifest for my app, when I have uploaded this app to the play store for some reason it is not visible for tablets.
What do I need to change to do this?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="1.0.2" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Comment: have you turned on xlargescreen to true.

Comment: <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to your manifest

```
 <supports-screens 
android:largeScreens="true" 
android:normalScreens="true" 
android:smallScreens="true" 
android:resizeable="true" 
android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

set uses feature required false in your manifest file
because some features are not supported by android tablets

for Example:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
```

while uploading to Google play it shows a yellow warning bubble next to your apk what message you are getting there?